# Filter by date using Datepicker ( AngularJS)

Tags: angularjs, filter, datepicker

Have a table that's display by "ng-repeat". Have a DatePicker. Need select date and after that will be filtering by date. My data save in object. I understand that datepicker format and my date format not equal. But I don't how to fix this.

HTML

```
    <thead>
        <th> <input type="date"  id="date" ng-model="getdate.date" /></th>
      </thead>
<tr ng-repeat="paymentinfo in paymentList | filter:getdate">
          <td>{{paymentinfo.date}}</td>
          <td>{{paymentinfo.name}}</td>

</tr>
```

My JS

```
angular.module('app.payment').controller('PaymentCtrl', ['$scope','$state', function($scope, $state){

$scope.paymentList = [
        {date:'06-12-2016', name : 'Pinao Class', remark : 'remarled', amount : 101},
        {date:'15.04.2016', name : 'drivers Class', remark : 'remarled', amount : 102},
        {date:'24.03.2016', name : 'Airplane Class', remark : 'remarled', amount : 103},
        {date:'28.02.2016', name : 'burger Class', remark : 'remarled', amount : 104},

    ];

}])
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

When dealing with date in javascript, I prefer to use external library like [moment](http://momentjs.com/)

Here is my version [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/KLIJkyoPKUIrhe6cnTXR?p=preview) for your answer, I don't know wether my answer is sufficient enough to answer your question.

Basically what I do is:

```
// model for datetime picker
$scope.dt = new Date();

// format to give to momentjs
$scope.dateFormatInTable = 'DD-MM-YYYY';

// data to display
$scope.datas = [
    {date:'06-12-2016', name : 'Pinao Class', remark : 'remarled', amount : 101},
    {date:'15-04-2016', name : 'drivers Class', remark : 'remarled', amount : 102},
    {date:'24-03-2016', name : 'Airplane Class', remark : 'remarled', amount : 103},
    {date:'28-02-2016', name : 'burger Class', remark : 'remarled', amount : 104},
];

// assign paymentList data
$scope.paymentList = $scope.datas;

// public function to filter the date
$scope.filterDate = function(dt) {
 var filteredDatas = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < $scope.datas.length; i++) {

   var xx = moment($scope.datas[i].date, $scope.dateFormatInTable).toDate();
   if (moment(xx).isSame(dt, 'day')) {
     filteredDatas.push($scope.datas[i]);
   }
 }
 $scope.paymentList = filteredDatas;
}

// reset filter
$scope.resetFilter = function() {
 $scope.paymentList = $scope.datas;
}
```

Comment: your plinker is empty, please update it. there just hello world

Comment: and give pls HTML

Comment: using your filter, when nothing select. nothing displaying. When select one date. showing all list

Comment: I connect only moments.js It's ok? because It's not work in my code. All code I copy. Don't understand why it happens

Comment: there is part of my full code https://plnkr.co/edit/Koa3oDnk8g5Y2pKLQjG3

Comment: find mistake. Thank you!

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/WAYHl2dzJYWgsWfDRjTO?p=info updated your plunker.

Comment: becomes empty after selecting

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that datepicker format and my date format not equal. But
>   I don't how to fix this.

When I use DatePicker, I fix the data in this way, maybe this code can help you!

Html code

```
<input type="text" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy" ng-model="dateFrom" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" is-open="statusData.opened" datepicker-options="{startingDay: 1}" current-text="Today" close-text="Close" clear-text="Clear" />
<button type="button" ng-click="openData($event)"<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
```

Controller-js code

```
$scope.format = 'dd/MM/yyyy';
//Some other code
$scope.finalDate = ($scope.dateFrom.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + ($scope.dateFrom.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + $scope.dateFrom.getDate()).slice(-2));
```

Comment: Instead of $scope.dateFrom you should use $scope.getdate.date, I suppose. If this is the date to format.

Comment: Cannot read property 'getFullYear' of undefined - I add your HTML but something wrong

Comment: Be carefull with dateFrom, this should be a string. Or at least I'm using this as a string.

Comment: Nope. Wrong. Nevermind. This should be a date! Checked it out right now! $scope.dateFrom should be a date. After the format it's resulting as a string

Comment: What I must do to fix this problem?

Comment: Can you make examle on plunkr ? May be I don't undertand something. or how to make it date format?

Comment: This error means that you are using 'getFullYear()' on a $scope that is undefined, there is no value this $scope. You should check why the $scope.yourDate is undefined.

Comment: Ok, I'm doing it on plunkr

Comment: $scope.dateFrom - I don't undertand how to define it, and where it defines   in your code

Comment: I created this one, in which you can check for the conversion.

Comment: Why I can't edit my mini-comment T_T  [conversion in datepicker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sd7LLaj2hMZmuYfDDZtH?p=preview)

Comment: Can you connect it with my ng-repeat?

Comment: I have updated the plunker, with filter on the ng-repeat connected with your code. Try to watch out! [update conversion in datepicker + filter for ng-repeat](http://plnkr.co/edit/sd7LLaj2hMZmuYfDDZtH?p=preview) Be carefull the date in the list have to be like '15.04.2016' width dots and dd.mm.yyyy Of course if you change a little bit the code, you can use even / - etc... Let me know if you are able to understand the code! :) I'm pretty new here, so yeah, maybe I make some mistakes xP

Comment: works great! but how to do this dynamicly? So I don't want use button? how makes it with out button?

Comment: I have update the plunker, with a double filter. [Update Plunker, double Filter](http://plnkr.co/edit/sd7LLaj2hMZmuYfDDZtH?p=preview) In the first one you can digit the date to filter the list. For apply the second one, you need to select the date than press the button. Let me know, if I understand well your request! :D